# Filter out approved code reviews in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have a few (~20) reviews in "Incoming reviews" section, and I would like to either move or filter out those that I did "Code-review" +2 or +1 myself. Preferably move to the other section "approved incoming reviews" or other comparable solution. Currently gerrit grays out subjects you approve, but it also grays out any other projects you post some comments. So it does not filter those efficiently, and you have to revisit every project. That is time waste.

I have tried to remove myself from the project after the approval, but such action removes approval as well.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion:

1) Click on ***YOUR-NAME*** > ***Settings***

2) Click on ***Preferences***

3) In ***My Menu*** add the following:

```
Name = Review (or other name you want)
URL  = #/q/reviewer:self+status:open+label:Code-Review=0%2Cuser=self
```

4) Click on ***Save Changes***

Now if you click on the new menu item: ***My*** > ***Review*** you will see all open changes you're a reviewer but don't have voted yet.